# Can't install Tesseract on Mac using brew install tesseract

Tags: python-3.x, macos, homebrew, tesseract, python-tesseract

I check my homebrew is the latest version (3.2.6).

But I can't still install tesseract using the following code on my macbook pro 2014-mid.

```
brew install tesseract
```

And it replied that

> Warning: No available formula or cask with the name "tesseract".

I also try the following code to check if the tesseract has been installed, but it seems to be null.

```
brew list tesseract
```

And it replied that

> Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/tesseract

Is there any setting should I do? Thanks!

Update 1:
I also try the following code, and still get the problem.

```
brew install wget
```

> Warning: No available formula or cask with the name "wget".

Answer (score 1):

After I try so many times, a Taiwanese netizen solve my problem.
The problem existed in the TAPS (third-party-repositories).

And I try the following code

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core
```

and then

```
brew tap homebrew/core
```

finally,

```
brew update
```